# How can I count up the total number of episodes per ID based on specific start and end criteria?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame("ID" = c(rep("A", times = 13),
                      rep("B", times = 7)),
                 "Value" = c(112,130,67,120,117,45,56,90,140,210,30,45,65,220,145,34,45,89,120,180))
```

I want to add a column that counts each episode. An episode is from the first occurrence of a value <70 to the first occurrence of a value >=70. Sometimes, there is never a value >=70 after the initial value <70, but it is still considered an episode.

I want a resulting dataframe that looks like this:

```
data<-data.frame("ID" = c(rep("A", times = 13),
                      rep("B", times = 7)),
                "Value" = c(112,130,67,120,117,45,56,90,140,210,30,45,65,220,145,34,45,89,120,180),
                "Episode" = c(NA,NA,1,1,NA,2,2,2,NA,NA,3,3,3,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,NA))
```

That way, I can summarize the number of episodes per ID:

```
final<-data.frame("ID" = c("A", "B"),
                 "Episodes" = c(3, 1))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to produce `final`, I think this works:

```
final <- data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(is_new_episode = if_else(lag(Value) < 70, 'same', 'new'),
         is_episode = if_else(Value < 70, 'episode', 'no_episode'),
         episode_start = is_episode == 'episode' & is_new_episode == 'new') %>% 
  summarize(Episodes = sum(episode_start))
```

Basically, you count which rows are the beginning of an episode.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), create a logical column based on the logical expression `Value < 70` and its `shift`ed output grouped by 'ID', using `rleid` (run-length-id - create a grouping variable on the similarity of adjacent elements of 'i1', grouped by 'ID', then specify the `i` as the 'i1', grouped by 'ID', `match` the 'grp' with `unique` elements of 'grp' and assign it to 'Episode'.  By default the elements that are not matched will be assigned to `NA`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, i1 := Reduce(`|`, list(Value < 70, 
               shift(Value < 70, fill = FALSE))), ID]
data[, grp := rleid(i1), ID]
data[as.logical(i1), Episode := match(grp, unique(grp)), ID][, 
               c('grp', 'i1') := NULL][]
#    ID Value Episode
# 1:  A   112      NA
# 2:  A   130      NA
# 3:  A    67       1
# 4:  A   120       1
# 5:  A   117      NA
# 6:  A    45       2
# 7:  A    56       2
# 8:  A    90       2
# 9:  A   140      NA
#10:  A   210      NA
#11:  A    30       3
#12:  A    45       3
#13:  A    65       3
#14:  B   220      NA
#15:  B   145      NA
#16:  B    34       1
#17:  B    45       1
#18:  B    89       1
#19:  B   120      NA
#20:  B   180      NA
```

From here, we can create the summarised output

```
data[, .(Episodes = uniqueN(Episode[!is.na(Episode)])), ID]
#   ID Episodes
#1:  A        3
#2:  B        1
```